# Allowing users to install a predefined bundle of plugins and themes with one action

Tags: plugins, themes, installation

**EDIT: Assuming one already has WP Core installed**; would it be possible to offer a predefined bundle of plugins and themes made by various parties, which users could download, and then install in (ideally) one action?

**E.g., could a plugin be made that does this? If so, what are the core considerations when creating such a plugin? Are there any limitations to plugins that would make this impossible?**

Other Notes:

- I am looking to offer this package/plugin for free.
- I would like to be able to provide a "download" button on a website (direct link to download the .zip file / plugin)
- My target users may not be comfortable using FTP, so I am leaning towards a plugin, if it would work (unless anyone has another idea).

Thank you.

Comment: What's the reason for asking this? I ask because it has a huge impact on the answer, as well as wether it will be useful to you. These kinds of questions are usually asked because they're an attempt to solve a problem or need that usually has a far better solution, e.g. distributing a product or deploying to servers, both of which have better/easier/simpler ways than bundles of themes/plugins/WP in a zip

Comment: Hi! I'd like to allow other users to deploy an installation that includes a predefined set of plugins and a theme; and/or install a bundle of plugins and theme with a single action—rather than create a tutorial requiring users to separately install all of the items independently themselves. I don't know how to be much more specific than that. But I guess I would basically be distributing a "product" that is open source, yes. Thanks! @TomJNowell!

Comment: Have you looked at GIT?

Comment: [Composer](https://getcomposer.org) is probably the most common tool for this kind of setup.

Comment: would I be right that you're selling something but it's a combination of a theme and plugins? If so that's super important context that needs to be stated clearly in the question otherwise you'll get answers that don't apply to you. If that is your use case then tools such as git/composer may not be that useful, even though they would be the correct answer. Use the edit link to modify your question to add context/why and be specific about what you're asking as well as the use case for it.

Comment: @TomJNowell In this case I am not selling somethings commercially. This could change, but for now it would be a free package. I will update my question accordingly, thanks.

Comment: So far this looks like the closest thing: https://wpcore.com.

Comment: note that you can't ask for a recomendation here, if it's a service or tool you're expecting as an answer then the software recommendations stack would be more appropraite

Answer (score 0):

> would it be possible to offer a predefined bundle of plugins and themes made by various parties, which users could download,

Yes, assuming you have the permission of those parties to use their branding and trademarks, and act within the GPL licence, you can just zip the plugins and theme up together and offer it as a download, however...

> and then install in (ideally) one action?

**No.**

The problem is that in order for such a thing to exist you would need to install a tool or install a downloader/installer plugin of some sort first, defeating the entire point of the exercise and making your install process very non-standard and unusual. Users would not be able to rely on familiar practices from other vendors, the .org documentation, or people online for help.

The closest you could get with WordPress core is:

1. unzip the file then use multiple WP CLI commands to chain install commands together for plugins and themes
2. Install a theme then have it automatically download and install the needed plugins

Option 1 is far beyond the capabilities of those uncomfortable with FTP, and option 2 could be problematic as the additional downloads and installs are a surprise, and include new complexity ( e.g. what if the plugins folder is readonly or managed by git? ).

Instead, it's easier to provide multiple zips in 1, or as multiple downloads, ensuring if the user doesn't install all of them, that the others will still work but with reduced functionality and a warning in the admin area. The user can easily install multiple items via multiple zips one at a time without any FTP/SSH knowledge.

The one case where what you want is *"possible"* is when using `composer`. Defining a package for each plugin/theme then declaring them as dependencies of a meta package would allow a user to run `composer install yourmetapackagesname` and it would fetch and install all of them. This is far beyond the abilities of someone struggling with FTP though and requires both SSH access, knowledge of CLI/terminals, and composer installed.

> EDIT: Assuming one already has WP Core installed;

The other case it's possible is when you pre-bundle them in a full WordPress install, but this would be suspicious and heavily implies that the copy of WordPress being bundled has.. *additions*

Comment: Thanks Tom; super helpful!